# Как подогнать все блоки под высоту самого высокого Bootstrap

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap

Я делаю блог на WordPress. Есть вывод постов, но за счет картинки, названия, превью все блоки в линии разной высоты и это бросается в глаза. Я не могу найти способа их выровнять. Перелопатил несколько способов на css.

1. Оказался не рабочим

   ```
   .row {
       display: table;

       div {
           display: table-cell;
       }
   }
   ```
2. С использованием flex,но bs с ним не дружит, после его использования все блоки встали в ряд и не работает сеточная система.

   ```
   .equal, .equal > div[class*='col-'] {
       display: -webkit-box;
       display: -moz-box;
       display: -ms-flexbox;
       display: -webkit-flex;
       display: flex;
       flex:1 0 auto; 
   }
   ```
3. Реализован на jq. Оказался рабочим но с одним НО. Картинки с блога подгружаются чуть с опозданием и высоту блока jq сначала берет без них, но потом картинки появляются и опускают за пределы блока название и превью поста (тк у блока маленькая высота).

   ```
   var highestBox = 0;
   jQuery('.content__block').each(function(){
       if(jQuery(this).height() > highestBox) {
           highestBox = jQuery(this).height(); //нахожу высоту самого высокого блока
       }
   });
   jQuery('.content__block').height(highestBox); //ставлю высоту самого высокого блока всем блокам
   ```

   На первой картинке jq сработал верно, но такое бывает 1 к 5.
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
   На второй проявился баг.
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно ли как то баг с jq исправить или же есть какой то способ на css?

P.S. у меня один блок с классом `.row`, и внутри него все блоки с классами `.col-*`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695784/how-can-i-make-bootstrap-columns-all-the-same-height

Comment: а просто inline-block пробовали ? или обычный css-table ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если во flexbox вам удалось выровнять блоки по высоте, то, чтобы вернуть сеточную систему, добавьте в контейнер

```
flex-wrap: wrap;
```

**P.S.:** вот хорошая полная [документация](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) по flexbox

Comment: спасибо помогло!